# Using nth-child to style item 4 and onwards

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a list item where I'd like the 4th item and onwards to have a different `background-color`.

I've tried the following:

```
li:nth-child(4) { background-color:blue; }
```

This styles only the 4th item. I then tried the following in the hope that it would style 4th item and onwards, but it didn't work:

```
li:nth-child(4+) { background-color:blue; }
```

How can I get this to work without having to specify 4th, 5th, 6th, 7th etc...?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use [`:nth-child(n+5)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/:nth-child) (CSS indexes start at 1).

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nTZrg/1/

```
li:nth-child(n+5) {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: In case you're interested, if you want to select Only the first 4 elements, use `:nth-child(-n+4)`: http://jsfiddle.net/nTZrg/2/

Comment: To anyone else reading this: I though I was taking crazy pills when I read the question and then looked at the answers (both seem to recommend `n+5`). What the OP actually needs/needed was `n+4` (item 4 and onwards).

Comment: As priidu says, li:nth-child(n+4)

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this

`li:nth-child(n+5) { background-color:blue; }`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/2p4e9/1/

Comment: li:nth-child(n+4)