# Apply a common class to html tags based on some condition using jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I have something like this -

```
<body>
<p >PARA1</p>
<p >PARA2</p>
<p>PARA3</p>
<p>PARA4</p>
<p>PARA5</p>
<p>PARA6</p>
<button>REMOVE</button>
</body>
```

I want to add 'new' class to the all the paragraphs after the 4th one using Jquery. My code-

```
$.each($('p').index > 4, function() {
                              $('p').addClass('new')
                            });
```

Can anyone please tell me how to fix this code?

Comment: Try this - `$.each($('p'), function(key, value) {
 if (index > 3) {
  $(this).addClass('new');
 }
});`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `:nth-child(n+5)` pseudo-selector to select the 4th child onward:

```
$('p:nth-child(n+5)').addClass('new');
```

[Using nth-child to style item 4 and onwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879423/using-nth-child-to-style-item-4-and-onwards)

Answer (score 1):

The `slice` method allows you to select all elements greater than or equal to the provided index.

```js
$('p').slice(4).addClass('new');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <p>PARA1</p>
    <p>PARA2</p>
    <p>PARA3</p>
    <p>PARA4</p>
    <p>PARA5</p>
    <p>PARA6</p>
    <button>REMOVE</button>
</body>
```

Comment: `:gt` is deprecated function and should not be used.

Answer (score 1):

> In case you want to use loop for doing more operations along with adding **new** class.

```js
$('p').each((i, para) => {
  if (i > 3) {
    $(para).addClass('new')
    // some other operations
  }
})
```

```css
.new {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <p>PARA1</p>
    <p>PARA2</p>
    <p>PARA3</p>
    <p>PARA4</p>
    <p>PARA5</p>
    <p>PARA6</p>
    <button>REMOVE</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
  $("p").slice(4).addClass("new");
```

The slice filter selects a sub-array starting the nth element of the returned jquery objects

https://api.jquery.com/slice/